# Selecting a type value in an interface or type object

Tags: typescript

How do I get a nested type object inside an interface or parent type?

```
interface IFake {
  button: {
    height: {
      dense: number;
      standard: number;
    };
  };
  otherStuff: string;
}

type Button = Pick<IFake, 'button'>

const aFunction = (button: Button) => button.height.dense
```

What I get:

```
// Button type is {
//   button: {
//     height: ...
//   }
// }
```

What I want:

```
// Button type is { height: ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do 
`type Button = IFake["button"];`

Comment: Thank you - can't believe I thought I couldn't do that with types.